# Timer does not stop in android

Tags: android, timer

I made an application in android and used timer like this..

```
try {
    CountDownTimer  start1 = new CountDownTimer(20000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                TextView timeShow = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.showTime);
        timeShow.setText(" "+" 00:" +millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            }
```

But my problem is i don't know how to stop timer. Any idea?

I already tried:

```
quitApplication.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) { 
        start1.cancel(); 
        Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), startGame.class);
        startActivity(i);
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`start1.cancel()` is the correct method to call to cancel the timer.

You did not provide any details about the error you got or why it didn't work for you, but I am assuming your program didn't compile because your variable `start1` is a **local variable**. It is probably local to whatever method your `try` block is in. This means your `OnClickListener` construction has no idea what `start1` is.

To fix this simply *declare* `start1` as a class variable (outside of all methods but within the class):

```
public class someClass {

CountDownTimer start1;
// blah some code
public void someMethod {
   try {
      start1 = new CountDownTimer() { //etc
```

Doing so will allow other methods to recognize and interact with `start1`

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a year old but for future readers you just need to call the timer as a final.

like so

```
final CountDownTimer  start1 = new CountDownTimer(20000, 1000) {}
```

that should work

Comment: Why would this make any difference?

Answer (score 1):

call start1.cancel() when you want to stop the timer

Comment: I used start1.cancel as following...
quitApplication.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
  {

   public void onClick(View v) 
   {
    
   start1.cancel();
    Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), startGame.class);
       startActivity(i);
       
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
   }
   
          
  });