# How to get the idle time or the time since last button being pressed?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-activity

In my module I have to perform some idle state events.I have gone through this [How to detect USER INACTIVITY in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208730/how-to-detect-user-inactivity-in-android) and [Android Best Way to Detect and Handle User INACTIVITY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5689591/android-best-way-to-detect-and-handle-user-inactivity) this tutorial..
now I just wanted to know how to get the last button pressed time so that if the any other button of my app is not being pressed for several seconds the idle state events should start..
please help me ....

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
public long startTime;
startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

then later on

```
public long elapsedTime;
elapsedTime = ( System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
```

then to break it down

```
int hour = (int)((((elapsedTime/1000)/60)/60)%60);
int minutes = (int)(((elapsedTime/1000)/60)%60);
int seconds = (int)((elapsedTime/1000)%60);
```