# CountDownTimer cancel method not working

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I was doing a basic test on "CountDownTimer" and after a particular sec i want to stop 
the countdowntimer completely. i used the method cancel but its not working the way i want
please help me out.

below is the complete code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    display = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtView);

    startTimer();


}
public void startTimer()
{
countDownTimer  =   new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

         public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
             secondsLeft =  millisUntilFinished / 1000;
             display.setText("seconds remaining: " +  secondsLeft );
             if(secondsLeft == 10)
             {
                 display.setText("CountDownTimer Canceled");
                 countDownTimer.cancel();
             }

         }

         public void onFinish() {
             display.setText("done!");
         }
      }.start();

}
```

Comment: When seconds equal to 10 timer stop or not?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to stop/cancel android CountDownTimer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138348/how-to-stop-cancel-android-countdowntimer)

Answer (score 1):

Try following code, worked for me

```
 if(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes( millisUntilFinished)==0<put min here> && TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) - 
                    TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))==50<put your seconds here>)
            {
             display.setText("CountDownTimer Canceled");
             countDownTimer.cancel();   
            }
```

Hope this will help