# CountDownTimer - EditText won't get an Integer

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

I keep getting "Application not responding" when trying to implement a CountDownTimer. Here's what I have:

```
private TextView mTextField;
private EditText secText;
private int secs;
private Button buttonStart, buttonStop;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTextField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    secText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.segText);
    buttonStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStart);
    buttonStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStop);
    secs = Integer.parseInt(secText.getText().toString());

    final CountDownTimer count = new CountDownTimer((secs*1000), 1000) {
         public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
             mTextField.setText("Seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
         }
         public void onFinish() {
             mTextField.setText("FINISHED!");
         }
      };
```

The problem is with this line when it tries to parse, if I put a number it works:

```
secs = Integer.parseInt(secText.getText().toString());
```

Comment: an edit text is awaiting a user input...what You do is that You directly parse an integer from Your editText which is not there....or have You set this number as a default value inside xml?

Comment: @Opiatefuchs I get your point. I tried with a number inside the xml and it works. Now I'll like to do it with the number that the user puts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you know the sequence of actions you need to perform. Here's some pseudo code

```
if buttonstart_clicked
    get text from sectext
    if text is empty
        show error
    else if text is notANumber
        show error
    else
        parse text AND start timer
```

You forgot your starting point is the button click, not the start of the application, because your edittext is still empty by then.

Comment: You're right. I just changed it and it kinda works, but since I've put it in the buttonStart, now how do I cancel it from another button's method?

Comment: Isnt that another question?

Comment: Yes. Thank you, anyway. It made me see my mistake.

Comment: @GorbyOz to cancel the CountdownTimer, check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138348/how-to-stop-cancel-android-countdowntimer

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle all the cases when trying to get the text from the `EditText`.

1. What if the `EditText` is empty?
2. What if the value in the `EditText` is not an Integer? ("1bs25", or "hello")

You need to consider these things and handle them properly before trying to parse the value into an Integer and start the timer.

Comment: I used this: `android:inputType="number"` to avoid string values.

Comment: Yes.  The point still stands that you aren't properly handling all possible cases when pulling the Editable from the EditText.  I see stealthjong worded the same response a bit differently and you understand now.  All good =)