# android countdowntimer can not stop

Tags: android, countdowntimer

Hi everyong I get the first time can not stopping the countdowntimer, i do not know why?

I used the variable to check log but do not know why it wrong?

Please help me

```
CountDownTimer timer = null;
boolean checkTimer;

private void startAnimation(int id) {
    checkTimer = false;
    Logger.error("runnable start");
    final View vv = mView.findViewById(R.id.viewKNXTop1);
    final View vv1 = mView.findViewById(R.id.viewKNXBot1);
    if (timer != null)
        timer.cancel();
    timer = new CountDownTimer(3000, 10) {

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            Logger.error("vv : " + vv.getBottom());
            Logger.error("vv1 : " + vv1.getTop());
            if (vv.getBottom() == vv1.getTop()) {
                checkTimer = true;
                Logger.error("= nhau rui na :v  ");
                timer.cancel();
            }
            if (!checkTimer) {
                vv.requestLayout();
                vv.getLayoutParams().height += bonusHeight;
                vv1.requestLayout();
                vv1.getLayoutParams().height += bonusHeight;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            Logger.error("runnable finished");
        }
    };
    timer.start();
}
```

i do not know why timer.cancel() not working. Here is my log:

```
01-28 07:47:00.211: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): runnable start
01-28 07:47:00.211: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 0
01-28 07:47:00.211: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 354
01-28 07:47:00.227: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 2
01-28 07:47:00.227: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 352
01-28 07:47:00.247: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 4
01-28 07:47:00.247: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 350
01-28 07:47:00.275: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 6
01-28 07:47:00.275: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 348
01-28 07:47:00.295: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 8
01-28 07:47:00.299: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 346
01-28 07:47:00.339: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 10
01-28 07:47:00.339: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 344
01-28 07:47:00.395: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 12
01-28 07:47:00.395: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 342
01-28 07:47:00.431: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 14
01-28 07:47:00.431: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 340
01-28 07:47:00.459: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 16
01-28 07:47:00.459: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 338
01-28 07:47:00.479: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 18
01-28 07:47:00.483: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 336
01-28 07:47:00.511: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 20
01-28 07:47:00.511: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 334
01-28 07:47:00.535: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 22
01-28 07:47:00.535: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 332
01-28 07:47:00.595: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 24
01-28 07:47:00.595: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 330
01-28 07:47:00.843: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 26
01-28 07:47:00.843: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 328
01-28 07:47:00.875: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 28
01-28 07:47:00.875: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 326
01-28 07:47:00.955: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 30
01-28 07:47:00.955: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 324
01-28 07:47:00.971: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 32
01-28 07:47:00.971: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 322
01-28 07:47:01.051: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 34
01-28 07:47:01.051: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 320
01-28 07:47:01.071: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 36
01-28 07:47:01.071: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 318
01-28 07:47:01.091: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 38
01-28 07:47:01.091: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 316
01-28 07:47:01.111: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 40
01-28 07:47:01.111: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 314
01-28 07:47:01.143: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 42
01-28 07:47:01.143: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 312
01-28 07:47:01.163: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 44
01-28 07:47:01.163: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 310
01-28 07:47:01.187: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 46
01-28 07:47:01.187: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 308
01-28 07:47:01.211: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 48
01-28 07:47:01.211: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 306
01-28 07:47:01.231: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 50
01-28 07:47:01.231: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 304
01-28 07:47:01.259: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 52
01-28 07:47:01.259: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 302
01-28 07:47:01.283: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 54
01-28 07:47:01.283: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 300
01-28 07:47:01.311: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 56
01-28 07:47:01.311: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 298
01-28 07:47:01.331: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 58
01-28 07:47:01.331: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 296
01-28 07:47:01.355: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 60
01-28 07:47:01.355: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 294
01-28 07:47:01.479: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 62
01-28 07:47:01.479: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 292
01-28 07:47:01.515: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 64
01-28 07:47:01.515: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 290
01-28 07:47:01.591: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 66
01-28 07:47:01.591: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 288
01-28 07:47:01.611: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 68
01-28 07:47:01.611: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 286
01-28 07:47:01.659: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 70
01-28 07:47:01.659: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 284
01-28 07:47:01.679: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 72
01-28 07:47:01.679: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 282
01-28 07:47:01.695: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 74
01-28 07:47:01.695: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 280
01-28 07:47:01.723: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 76
01-28 07:47:01.723: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 278
01-28 07:47:01.739: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 78
01-28 07:47:01.739: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 276
01-28 07:47:01.755: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 80
01-28 07:47:01.755: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 274
01-28 07:47:01.779: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 82
01-28 07:47:01.779: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 272
01-28 07:47:01.803: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 84
01-28 07:47:01.803: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 270
01-28 07:47:01.827: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 86
01-28 07:47:01.827: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 268
01-28 07:47:01.843: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 88
01-28 07:47:01.843: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 266
01-28 07:47:01.863: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 90
01-28 07:47:01.863: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 264
01-28 07:47:01.887: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 92
01-28 07:47:01.887: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 262
01-28 07:47:01.911: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 94
01-28 07:47:01.911: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 260
01-28 07:47:01.927: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 96
01-28 07:47:01.927: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 258
01-28 07:47:01.947: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 98
01-28 07:47:01.947: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 256
01-28 07:47:01.963: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 100
01-28 07:47:01.963: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 254
01-28 07:47:01.987: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 102
01-28 07:47:01.987: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 252
01-28 07:47:02.007: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 104
01-28 07:47:02.007: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 250
01-28 07:47:02.023: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 106
01-28 07:47:02.023: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 248
01-28 07:47:02.043: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 108
01-28 07:47:02.043: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 246
01-28 07:47:02.059: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 110
01-28 07:47:02.059: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 244
01-28 07:47:02.079: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 112
01-28 07:47:02.079: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 242
01-28 07:47:02.095: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 114
01-28 07:47:02.095: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 240
01-28 07:47:02.111: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 116
01-28 07:47:02.111: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 238
01-28 07:47:02.127: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 118
01-28 07:47:02.127: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 236
01-28 07:47:02.139: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 120
01-28 07:47:02.139: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 234
01-28 07:47:02.159: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 122
01-28 07:47:02.159: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 232
01-28 07:47:02.183: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 124
01-28 07:47:02.183: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 230
01-28 07:47:02.203: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 126
01-28 07:47:02.203: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 228
01-28 07:47:02.227: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 128
01-28 07:47:02.227: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 226
01-28 07:47:02.247: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 130
01-28 07:47:02.247: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 224
01-28 07:47:02.271: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 132
01-28 07:47:02.271: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 222
01-28 07:47:02.291: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 134
01-28 07:47:02.291: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 220
01-28 07:47:02.315: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 136
01-28 07:47:02.315: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 218
01-28 07:47:02.339: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 138
01-28 07:47:02.339: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 216
01-28 07:47:02.359: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 140
01-28 07:47:02.359: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 214
01-28 07:47:02.379: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 142
01-28 07:47:02.379: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 212
01-28 07:47:02.395: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 144
01-28 07:47:02.395: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 210
01-28 07:47:02.411: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 146
01-28 07:47:02.411: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 208
01-28 07:47:02.427: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 148
01-28 07:47:02.427: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 206
01-28 07:47:02.443: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 150
01-28 07:47:02.443: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 204
01-28 07:47:02.459: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 152
01-28 07:47:02.459: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 202
01-28 07:47:02.475: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 154
01-28 07:47:02.475: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 200
01-28 07:47:02.495: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 156
01-28 07:47:02.495: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 198
01-28 07:47:02.511: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 158
01-28 07:47:02.511: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 196
01-28 07:47:02.527: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 160
01-28 07:47:02.527: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 194
01-28 07:47:02.543: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 162
01-28 07:47:02.543: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 192
01-28 07:47:02.563: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 164
01-28 07:47:02.563: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 190
01-28 07:47:02.587: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 166
01-28 07:47:02.587: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 188
01-28 07:47:02.603: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 168
01-28 07:47:02.603: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 186
01-28 07:47:02.619: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 170
01-28 07:47:02.619: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 184
01-28 07:47:02.635: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 172
01-28 07:47:02.635: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 182
01-28 07:47:02.655: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 174
01-28 07:47:02.655: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 180
01-28 07:47:02.671: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 176
01-28 07:47:02.671: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 178
01-28 07:47:02.687: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 178
01-28 07:47:02.691: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 178
01-28 07:47:02.691: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): = nhau rui na :v  
01-28 07:47:02.699: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 178
01-28 07:47:02.699: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 178
01-28 07:47:02.699: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): = nhau rui na :v  
01-28 07:47:02.711: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 178
01-28 07:47:02.711: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 178
01-28 07:47:02.711: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): = nhau rui na :v  
01-28 07:47:02.719: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 178
01-28 07:47:02.719: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 178
01-28 07:47:02.719: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): = nhau rui na :v  
01-28 07:47:02.731: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 178
01-28 07:47:02.731: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 178
01-28 07:47:02.731: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): = nhau rui na :v  
01-28 07:47:02.739: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 178
01-28 07:47:02.739: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 178
01-28 07:47:02.739: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): = nhau rui na :v  
01-28 07:47:02.751: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 178
01-28 07:47:02.751: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 178
01-28 07:47:02.751: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): = nhau rui na :v  
01-28 07:47:02.763: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 178
01-28 07:47:02.763: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 178
01-28 07:47:02.763: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): = nhau rui na :v  
01-28 07:47:02.775: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 178
01-28 07:47:02.775: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 178
01-28 07:47:02.775: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): = nhau rui na :v  
01-28 07:47:02.783: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 178
01-28 07:47:02.783: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 178
01-28 07:47:02.783: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): = nhau rui na :v  
01-28 07:47:02.795: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 178
01-28 07:47:02.795: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 178
01-28 07:47:02.795: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): = nhau rui na :v  
01-28 07:47:02.807: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 178
01-28 07:47:02.807: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 178
01-28 07:47:02.807: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): = nhau rui na :v  
01-28 07:47:02.815: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 178
01-28 07:47:02.815: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 178
01-28 07:47:02.815: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): = nhau rui na :v  
01-28 07:47:02.827: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 178
01-28 07:47:02.827: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 178
01-28 07:47:02.827: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): = nhau rui na :v  
01-28 07:47:02.839: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 178
01-28 07:47:02.839: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 178
01-28 07:47:02.839: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): = nhau rui na :v  
01-28 07:47:02.847: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 178
01-28 07:47:02.847: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 178
01-28 07:47:02.847: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): = nhau rui na :v  
01-28 07:47:02.863: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 178
01-28 07:47:02.863: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 178
01-28 07:47:02.863: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): = nhau rui na :v  
01-28 07:47:02.871: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 178
01-28 07:47:02.871: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 178
01-28 07:47:02.871: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): = nhau rui na :v  
01-28 07:47:02.883: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 178
01-28 07:47:02.883: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 178
01-28 07:47:02.883: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): = nhau rui na :v  
01-28 07:47:02.891: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 178
01-28 07:47:02.891: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 178
01-28 07:47:02.891: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): = nhau rui na :v  
01-28 07:47:02.903: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 178
01-28 07:47:02.903: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 178
01-28 07:47:02.903: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): = nhau rui na :v  
01-28 07:47:02.915: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 178
01-28 07:47:02.915: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 178
01-28 07:47:02.915: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): = nhau rui na :v  
01-28 07:47:02.923: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 178
01-28 07:47:02.923: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 178
01-28 07:47:02.923: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): = nhau rui na :v  
01-28 07:47:02.935: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 178
01-28 07:47:02.935: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 178
01-28 07:47:02.935: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): = nhau rui na :v  
01-28 07:47:02.943: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 178
01-28 07:47:02.943: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 178
01-28 07:47:02.943: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): = nhau rui na :v  
01-28 07:47:02.955: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 178
01-28 07:47:02.955: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 178
01-28 07:47:02.955: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): = nhau rui na :v  
01-28 07:47:02.963: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 178
01-28 07:47:02.963: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 178
01-28 07:47:02.963: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): = nhau rui na :v  
01-28 07:47:02.975: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 178
01-28 07:47:02.975: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 178
01-28 07:47:02.975: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): = nhau rui na :v  
01-28 07:47:02.987: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 178
01-28 07:47:02.987: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 178
01-28 07:47:02.987: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): = nhau rui na :v  
01-28 07:47:02.991: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 178
01-28 07:47:02.991: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 178
01-28 07:47:02.991: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): = nhau rui na :v  
01-28 07:47:03.007: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 178
01-28 07:47:03.007: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 178
01-28 07:47:03.007: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): = nhau rui na :v  
01-28 07:47:03.019: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 178
01-28 07:47:03.019: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 178
01-28 07:47:03.019: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): = nhau rui na :v  
01-28 07:47:03.027: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 178
01-28 07:47:03.031: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 178
01-28 07:47:03.031: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): = nhau rui na :v  
01-28 07:47:03.035: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 178
01-28 07:47:03.035: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 178
01-28 07:47:03.035: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): = nhau rui na :v  
01-28 07:47:03.047: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 178
01-28 07:47:03.047: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 178
01-28 07:47:03.051: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): = nhau rui na :v  
01-28 07:47:03.055: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 178
01-28 07:47:03.055: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 178
01-28 07:47:03.055: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): = nhau rui na :v  
01-28 07:47:03.071: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 178
01-28 07:47:03.071: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 178
01-28 07:47:03.071: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): = nhau rui na :v  
01-28 07:47:03.075: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 178
01-28 07:47:03.075: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 178
01-28 07:47:03.079: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): = nhau rui na :v  
01-28 07:47:03.091: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 178
01-28 07:47:03.091: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 178
01-28 07:47:03.091: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): = nhau rui na :v  
01-28 07:47:03.103: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 178
01-28 07:47:03.103: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 178
01-28 07:47:03.103: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): = nhau rui na :v  
01-28 07:47:03.111: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 178
01-28 07:47:03.111: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 178
01-28 07:47:03.111: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): = nhau rui na :v  
01-28 07:47:03.123: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 178
01-28 07:47:03.123: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 178
01-28 07:47:03.123: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): = nhau rui na :v  
01-28 07:47:03.135: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 178
01-28 07:47:03.135: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 178
01-28 07:47:03.135: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): = nhau rui na :v  
01-28 07:47:03.143: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 178
01-28 07:47:03.143: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 178
01-28 07:47:03.143: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): = nhau rui na :v  
01-28 07:47:03.155: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 178
01-28 07:47:03.155: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 178
01-28 07:47:03.155: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): = nhau rui na :v  
01-28 07:47:03.163: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 178
01-28 07:47:03.163: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 178
01-28 07:47:03.163: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): = nhau rui na :v  
01-28 07:47:03.175: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 178
01-28 07:47:03.175: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 178
01-28 07:47:03.175: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): = nhau rui na :v  
01-28 07:47:03.179: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 178
01-28 07:47:03.179: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 178
01-28 07:47:03.179: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): = nhau rui na :v  
01-28 07:47:03.195: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv : 178
01-28 07:47:03.195: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): vv1 : 178
01-28 07:47:03.195: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): = nhau rui na :v  
01-28 07:47:03.211: E/IO_LAUNCH APP(3444): runnable finished
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to stop/cancel android CountDownTimer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138348/how-to-stop-cancel-android-countdowntimer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to cancel in separate thread like

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mCountDownTimer.cancel();

                    }
                }).start();
```